# Query a duplicate data from two different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables on DBA.

```
Table1: name_id | id | lastupdated | name

Table2: user_id | action_view | mob_no | process | result
```

These two tables are related with name_id=user_id.

I want to query all the users, that have the same mobile number for whom column `result` is 1 (meaning successful).

Lets say for Name(John in Table1) we have 3 different mobile numbers in table 2 and for each the `result` is 1.

Comment: take a look at JOIN queries

Comment: please add name_id on table2 that way every record from table2 is properly referenced from table1 the use join when you query